# Getting npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, when trying to create react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Basically when i'm trying to create a react app using

`npx create-react-app chat-app`

I'm getting this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5nhd.png)

I tried following things to remove error:

1. First to check weather i'm running behind the proxy or not i executed this command:

`npm config get proxy`

So i got "null" as output

2. Then i tried set registry as well using:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

3. Then i even tried to set the timeout to 60000
4. I also tried to exeute:

`npm cache clean --force`

Other than this my network connectivity is also good and i tried switching it as well. My node version is also the latest one.

After trying all these also i'm getting the same error

Please help me find the solution for this error

Comment: Please try this "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" in your terminal. And then run your project again after installation of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command with verbose output might provide additional information about the issue. Try using the --verbose flag when creating the React app

> `npx --verbose create-react-app chat-app`

Comment: Please try this "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" in your terminal. And then run your project after installation of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

> npm install create-react-app

again , after clean force command ?

also Follow These Steps might be help :

> npm cache clean --force
>
> npm uninstall -g create-react-app
>
> npm uninstall create-react-app
>
> npm install create-react-app
>
> npx create-react-app app_name

you can also switch to, yarn create react-app app_name